# FastMM4 states there are memory leaks in Quick.Logger, what am I doing wrong

Tags: delphi, logging

Maybe I am doing it wrong, but I am trying to have the logs flush and so I made a method:

```pascal
...
implementation

uses
  Quick.Logger,
  Quick.Logger.Provider.Files,
  Quick.Logger.ExceptionHook;
...
procedure FinalizeLogger; stdcall;
var
  count: Integer;
begin
  Log('Logger shutdown', etInfo);
  // Force the logger to flush any buffered messages.
  if Assigned(Logger) then
  begin
    count := Logger.QueueCount;
    Log('There are %d log items in queue.', [count], etInfo);
  end;

  if Assigned(GlobalLogFileProvider) then
  begin
    GlobalLogFileProvider.Drain;
    GlobalLogFileProvider.Stop;
  end;
end;

procedure InitializeLogger; stdcall;
begin
  Logger.Providers.Add(GlobalLogFileProvider);
  with GlobalLogFileProvider do
  begin
    FileName := 'D:\Source\Delphi\WalterWrapper\Logs\Native.log';
    // Specify an absolute path for debugging
    DailyRotate := True;
    MaxFileSizeInMB := 20;
    LogLevel := LOG_ALL;
    Enabled := True;
  end;

  Log('Logger initialized', etInfo);
end;
```

I have a unit test, I had no issues, and when I add `Quick.Logger` via GetIt and integrate it, I get a error. This is my unit test that uses logging in my use cases:

```pascal
[TestFixture]
EncyptionTest = class
  public
    [Setup]
    procedure Setup;
    [TearDown]
    procedure TearDown;
    [Test]
    procedure DeriveKeyFromPasswordTest;
    [Test]
    procedure DeriveSameKeyFromPasswordTest;
    [Test]
    procedure RoundTripTest;
  end;

procedure EncyptionTest.Setup;
begin
  InitializeLogger;
end;

procedure EncyptionTest.TearDown;
begin
  FinalizeLogger;
end;
```

I must have something wrong in my `FinalizeLogger` method, not sure what I can do. There is no documentation on the site that I can find how to force the log to flush.

Any suggestions?

Here is the first part of the log file, like it's not closing:

```
--------------------------------2024/3/14 21:32:16--------------------------------
A memory block has been leaked. The size is: 40

This block was allocated by thread 0x9078, and the stack trace (return addresses) at the time was:
E657E7 [FastMM4.pas][FastMM4][_ZN7Fastmm411DebugGetMemEx][9670]
E1D124 [System][_ZN6System7_GetMemEx]
E22821 [System][_ZN6System7TObject11NewInstanceEv]
E23421 [System][_ZN6System12_ClassCreateEPva]
FB22E1 [System.Classes][_ZN6System7Classes11TFileStreamC3ENS_13UnicodeStringEt]
1225534 [Quick.Logger.Provider.Files.pas][Quick.Logger.Provider.Files][_ZN5Quick6Logger8Provider5Files16TLogFileProvider4InitEv][192]
11FB9E0 [Quick.Logger.pas][Quick.Logger][_ZN5Quick6Logger16TLogProviderBase10SetEnabledEb][1032]
122732B [StringUtils.pas][StringUtils][_ZN11Stringutils16InitializeLoggerEv][49]
128CCD1 [EncryptionTests.pas][EncryptionTests][_ZN15Encryptiontests13EncyptionTest5SetupEv][32]
1124DC1 [DUnitX.TestRunner][_ZN6Dunitx10Testrunner17TDUnitXTestRunner22ExecuteTestSetupMethodEN6System15DelphiInterfaceINS_18Internalinterfaces19ITestExecuteContextEEEjNS3_INS_13Extensibility12ITestFixtureEEENS3_INS7_5ITestEEERNS3_INS_13Testframework11ITestResul
112478D [DUnitX.TestRunner][_ZN6Dunitx10Testrunner17TDUnitXTestRunner12ExecuteTestsEN6System15DelphiInterfaceINS_18Internalinterfaces19ITestExecuteContextEEEjNS3_INS_13Extensibility12ITestFixtureEEENS3_INS_13Testframework14IFixtureResultEEE]

The block is currently used for an object of class: System.Classes.TFileStream

The allocation number is: 11973
```

Comment: The leak log says there is a `TFileStream` object being created inside of `InitializeLogger()` which is not being destroyed (or at least hasn't been destroyed *yet* when the leak is reported). What does `InitializeLogger()` look like? I see you *stopping* the Logger, but where do you actually *destroy* the Logger? Presumably it has a `TFileStream` member that is not destroyed until the Logger itself is destroyed. When using global singletons, sometimes they are simply not destroyed before the leak report is generated, but get destroyed afterwards, so this may just be a false positive situation

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I have added the method, basically it's from the sample on the  Quick.Logger GitHub amd online documentation. From what I see there are several memory leaks, i just included the first of the logfile. 

As it's in GetIt I was hoping some one knows how to property release the memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding `GlobalLogFileProvider` at least twice to the `Logger.Providers` it is creating a circular reference that is keeping itself alive.

However `Logger.Providers.Remove(GlobalLogFileProvider)` will not work because then the `GlobalLogFileProvider` instance will be destroyed because its reference count will drop to 0.

This is the result of an unfortunate design in the Quick.Logger library because it mixes object and interface references and causes some circular interface references that are not being resolved in some situations such as in `TLogger.OnProviderListNotify` and `TLogProviderBase.Init`.